# how to store values in drupal database of contact form with contact module

Tags: database, forms, drupal, module, contacts

I am using contact module in drupal.
but in contact module have only email send functionality..
But i want to store all values all values in database without use custom code.
Please suggest me any module is available for this in drupal

Answer (score 0):

Use [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module. It allows you to build any custom form and store all values in database. You can even set some permission to review user submissions.